# ifselectedindex changed , show data in a textbox

Tags: vb.net, combobox, visual-studio-2019, richtextbox, selectedindexchanged

I've linked an access database to my form.
I have 1 table , 2 rows
1 = Researchtype short text
2 = Researchdetails (long text)

In my combobox1 i've binded my researchtype row so i can choose a type of research.

Question now: how can i bind the details data to the richtextbox below it in order to show the research data as soon as i choose a research type?

I've tried if else combos, try catch combos,
i'm thinking i'm actually overthinking the issue here.

What would be the easiest way to "select from dropdown" and show the result in textbox.
I'm a vb.net beginner

```
Public Class Onderzoeken
    Private Sub Onderzoeken_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'PatientenDatabaseDataSetX.tbl_OnderzoeksTypes' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.Tbl_OnderzoeksTypesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PatientenDatabaseDataSetX.tbl_OnderzoeksTypes)
    End Sub

    Private Sub cboxOnderzoek_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboxOnderzoek.SelectedIndexChanged
        If cboxOnderzoek.SelectedItem = Nothing Then

            cboxOnderzoek.Text = ""
        Else
            rtbBeschrijvingOnderzoek.Text = CStr(CType(cboxOnderzoek.SelectedItem, DataRowView)("OZ_Onderzoeksbeschrijving"))

        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

I added the entire code of that page now , it's not much, but as stated: I added the binding source and displaymember "researchtype" to the combobox.
So when i start the form, i can choose a type of research.
Now i need to show the description of the research in the richtextbox

Comment: Can you show the code that queries the database and returns a selection of records? What type of collection is that? -- Did you try to bind the Text property of your RTB to a Column of the data source? Don't post that code in comments, edit your question instead.

Comment: for this i just used the properties of the combox to add the databinding from the access database, i can show a screenshot?

Comment: Btw, since you have just two Columns which should be both bound to Controls, you don't need to handle the ˆSelectedIndexChangedˆ event at all.

Comment: for some reason i cannot bind data to the richtextbox as i could with the combobox though

Comment: Why? Can't you write something like: `RichTextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", PatientenDatabaseDataSetX.tbl_OnderzoeksTypes, "Researchdetails", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)`?

Comment: hmm, i seem to get errors when i switch research type?
System.ArgumentException: 'Op deze manier worden twee bindingen in de verzameling aan dezelfde eigenschap gebonden.
Parameternaam: binding'
english: this way 2 bindings in the collection are bound to the same property
parameter name : binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Form.Load`...

I have a function that returns a `DataTable` that contains columns called `Name` and `Type`. I bind the ComboBox to the `DataTable` and set the `DisplayMember` to `"Name"`. Each Item in the ComboBox contains the entire `DataRowView`. I set the `TextBox` to the first row (`dt(0)("Type")`) `Type` column value so the correct information will be displayed for the initial selection.

I put the code to change the textbox display in `ComboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted` because the other change events will produce a NRE since `.SelectedItem` has not yet been set when the form loads. The commited event will only occur when the user makes a selection.

First, cast the `SelectedItem` to its underlying type, `DataRowView`. Then you want the value of the `Type` column. This value is assigned to the text property of the textbox.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim dt = LoadCoffeeTable()
    ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
    TextBox1.Text = dt(0)("Type").ToString
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted
    TextBox1.Text = DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, DataRowView)("Type").ToString
End Sub
```

Just substitute `Researchtype` for `Name` and `Researchdetails` for `Type`.

Comment: took a while to find out everything you wrote @Mary but it works ! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After using 'OleDbDataAdapter' to fill the dataset, you can set 'DisplayMember' and 'ValueMember' for your ComboBox. Every time the index of your ComboBox changes, it's 'ValueMember' will be displayed in richtextbox.

Here's the code you can refer to.

```
Private dataset As DataSet = New DataSet()
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim connString As String = "your connection String"
    Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(connString)
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Researchtype, Researchdetails FROM yourtable"
        Dim adpt As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        adpt.Fill(dataset)
    End Using
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Researchtype"
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Researchdetails"
    ComboBox1.DataSource = dataset.Tables(0)
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    RichTextBox1.Text = ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()
End Sub
```

Result of my test.

[image]

Comment: hey there, thanks for your reply, i get an error when i try it your way : 
System.NullReferenceException: 'De objectverwijzing is niet op een exemplaar van een object ingesteld.'
object reference is not configured to a part of the object?